# How to avoid blinking in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I developed a simple jquery ajax php application. I done a pagination. In that the pages could load by using AJAX. When ever user clicks on the page number in the pagination. I can able to see some window blink. How i can avoid this problem? The problem because of the scroll bar or what?

Comment: you'll need to be a bit more clear. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but if the problem is caused by the scrollbar you should look at the overflow css property:
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Set this property to scroll:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another problem might be that if you are fade-ing the elements to hide the old and show the new content, you might need to get them nested, like this:

```
$("#content").fadeOut(400, function(){
   // this gets executed when fadeOut has completed
   $("#content").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another problem, and this might actually be my best bet, is that when you erase the old content, the site height drops to let's say 200px, a very low number, and your browser scrollbar gets erased -> the site moves right about 5px. Then, when the new content is loaded, the site is long in height again and the scrollbar is visible again -> the site moves back left. All this happens extremely fast and it might look like a blink that you described. Is this your problem? If yes, I'll give you the solution.